# What's the cmd / batch alternative to the deprecated wmic?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, wmic

I'm aware of `wmic` being deprecated as of 2012 and I now typically use PowerShell anyway, so had moved away from it already.

However, I frequently encounter cases where I need to work within batch files and do not have the option of migrating the solution to PowerShell.

My question is this: with `wmic` deprecated, what is the recommended alternative for continued access to the Windows Management Instrumentation from the command prompt and from batch files?

The best I can think of currently is something along the lines of:

```
powershell -command "(Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor) | select *" | some_other_program.exe
```

(this example to get processor attributes)

But one major downside of that is that errorlevels and the environment are no longer accessible. That is, the powershell command completes successfully, even if the command does not). And changes made to the environment in the powershell command do not propagate to the batch file.

Any suggestions on how to specifically address those issues, or on better alternatives to calling powershell from the batch for access to WMI are welcome, but specifically I'd like to know how to run a powershell command and access the results other than the standard out.

Comment: Whilst you state it's deprecated, you haven't expanded upon that statement or how it affects your real world scenario. `WMIC.exe` is still a working program on the Windows 10 PC's I've used. Also there's no reason why you cannot run a powershell command from a batch file  `in` a `for` loop to receive it's returned output in the `do`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I frequently encounter cases where I need to work within batch files and do not have the option of migrating the solution to PowerShell." Why not?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart these will be cases where the clients I do work for have existing batch files that need amending and they're simply not willing to pay for the time to migrate everything - or don't have the capability (or willingness) to maintain something new.

Comment: @Compo - that's absolutely fair and currently, it doesn't. I expect that Microsoft's move to deprecate it means that in the near future, we can expect functionality that matters to no longer be available through `wmic.exe`, forcing me to use PowerShell functionality if I need it. Since I'd prefer to follow a good pattern if it's available to me, I'm asking the question - also since there already are functions available in PowerShell that are tricky in cmd (like Azure management), so there's already some cases where a good solution would be useful.

Comment: @Compo, how can I receive the output from a powershell command (other than standard out, as mentioned in the question) in the batch file? I.e. errorlevels and changes to the environment or otherwise local changes (like PowerShell variables). If you know the answer to that, please post as an answer - but from what you're saying, I think you're just talking about standard out.

Comment: @Grismar, bear in mind that `XCopy` is deprecated, _and has been since it was superceded by `RoboCopy` in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008_. It still however exists on your system today 'for backward compatibility'. If we're being really sensible, we'd stop using cmd.exe as it's also come to its end of life, Windows 10 users can now download and use a preview app called Windows Terminal, which has an Azure Cloud Shell, cmd, and powershell.exe which is technically cmd.exe's natural replacement.

Comment: @compo copying files is copying files - I'm referring to new functionality that won't be directly available in any form from the old command prompt. The Azure modules are a good example, I think. I'm not sure what your point is here. I'm not worried about deprecated modules going away. Apart from that, if you argument is that "some deprecated elements are still around, so using deprecated elements as a rule is a good idea", I disagree.

Comment: @compo also - I don't "state it's deprecated" - it's the application itself that feels the need to tell its users in red text when you run it for certain commands.

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea @Grismar. Remember that you stated that you needed the functionality because you needed to maintain, _'amend'_, existing client scripts. If the functionality is there for their older scripts, they'll generally still be there in future. Your clients aren't asking for you to amend scripts which contain functionality not yet available, after all!

Comment: @compo - not currently they aren't, but when making changes to current scripts, the deprecation message came up. That led me to look into other ways of using the WMI, since it's highly likely that requests will keep coming and I'd prefer to use a way of working that sets the standard for future requests. You may not agree with the practice, but I don't quite see what your argument is here.

Comment: I'm not arguing, I'm simply repeating what you've told us. If your clients need functionality available using tools available to them, and are not willing to use those tools then they cannot have what they want. Your question is about something which hasn't happened yet, so how can we reasonably solve something which hasn't happened. Powershell 2.0 was available in Windows 7, 10 years ago, its not as if there hasn't been sufficient time for your clients to adapt. If those clients in the future are unwilling to change tell them that they cannot have their scripts amended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But one major downside of that is that errorlevels and the environment are no longer accessible.

The simplest way to **make a PowerShell command invoked via the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)** (`powershell.exe` in Windows PowerShell, `pwsh` in PowerShell (Core) 7+) **report a nonzero exit code** is to **throw a script-terminating (thread-terminating) error**, which results in error code `1` - which your batch file can test for:

```
@echo off

:: # Simulate a failing CIM call
powershell -c "$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'; Get-CimInstance Win32_NoSuchClass" 

:: # Exit, if the PowerShell command failed.
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Error: Get-CimInstance failed>&2 & exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

echo Moving on...
```

`$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'` at the start of the command ensures that any subsequent error becomes a script-terminating one.
To ignore non-terminating errors selectively, use `-ErrorAction Ignore` command-individually.
If no error occurs, the exit code is implicitly `0`.

<sup>PowerShell's error handling is bewilderingly complex; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) for a comprehensive summary.</sup>

Note:

- Native PowerShell commands such as `Get-CimInstance` do not set exit codes; the best you can do is to map errors to exit code `1`, and success to exit code `0`.
- If you call external programs from PowerShell, their exit code is reflected in automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE`; you can use `exit $LASTEXITCODE` to pass that exit code through from your PowerShell command string; however, you can generally simply call external programs from your batch file directly - no detour via PowerShell needed.

---

> And changes made to the environment in the powershell command do not propagate to the batch file.

True, the PowerShell command invariably runs in a *child process*, whose environment has no impact on the calling process.

Generally:

- Capture *output* from the PowerShell command in a file or process it in memory with a `for /f` loop (see example below) - unless passing the output *through* is sufficient.
- If you truly need to modify the calling batch file's *environment*, have the PowerShell command output the *data* for those modifications, and apply them in the batch file.

  - E.g., if you want your PowerShell command to set environment variables, make it output `<name>=<value>` string pairs that the batch file can use to set these variables.

An example of tailoring output from a PowerShell command for parsing in a batch file with `for /f`; note that the quoting can get tricky:

```
@echo off

:: # Get the .Name and .MaxClockSpeed property values from the Win32_Processor instance.
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('powershell -c "$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'; Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | %% { foreach ($n in 'Name', 'MaxClockSpeed') { \""$n=$($_.$n)\"" } }"') do (
  echo [%%i]=[%%j]
)

:: # Exit, if the PowerShell command failed.
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Error: Get-CimInstance failed>&2 & exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The above yields something like:

```
[Name]=[Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz]
[MaxClockSpeed]=[2304]
```

Comment: Thanks for adding to it - I'll accept your response as the answer, although I think the takeaway for anyone looking for an answer to a similar question should be: there's no way of doing it in a straightforward way - you need to implement some relatively clean workaround like the ones you're suggesting.

Comment: Thanks, @Grismar: I agree - this is as good as it gets; PowerShell never has been and still isn't great when it comes to interacting with the outside world - only _partly_ of necessity. Compromises and pain points are inevitable.